# Reload single entity followed by increment and save changes causes dirty reads

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I have the following code which runs in only one web application. I want to make sure that the value is incremented by 1 and that I don't get into problems because of dirty reads.
I am curious why this code may cause dirty reads sometimes?

```cs
_locker.EnterWriteLock(); // static ReaderWriterLockSlim _locker= new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
var task = _dbo.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.TaskId == taskId);
_dbo.Entry<Task>(task).Reload();
task.Commits += noOfCommits;
_dbo.SaveChanges();
locker.ExitWriteLock();
```

`_dbo` is instantiated every request

Comment: Why are you reloading the task after getting it from the db?

Comment: I assume that it was loaded before and I am getting a cached version of it while it was updated in another thread/request.